# Why iIam getting Eaccess permission denied on my mac m1?

Tags: docker, permissions, node-modules, apple-m1, appsody

I am trying to run my application through [appsody](https://appsody.dev/). When I run my application there is a folder which generates on run time. Even though I have given access rights to all the users ( admin, myself, staff, everyone ) for that parent directory where this folder will be created but i get permission denied access.

Steps I have done so far.

1. I used to run my command with sudo ( not worked )
2. I watched this [permission denied video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxvybxYFq2o) on youtube and applied the steps ( not worked )
3. I even tried to create that folder manually and open all read and write permissions, but when I run my app and the app wants to access that folder it gets denied. ( not worked )
4. Have given permission 755 to that folder ( not worked )

Below is my docker file

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/nodejs-12:1-59

USER root

# Install OS updates
RUN yum install --disableplugin=subscription-manager python2 -y \
    && yum clean --disableplugin=subscription-manager packages \
    && ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid 0 --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

RUN npm -v

COPY jazzcash-appsody-stack/image/project/package*.json /project/
COPY jazzcash-appsody-stack/image/project/*.js /project/
COPY . /project/user-app/
RUN rm -rf /project/user-app/node_modules && mkdir -p /project/user-app/node_modules

RUN chown -hR root:0 /project

# Install stack dependencies
WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --production

# Install user-app dependencies
WORKDIR /project/user-app
RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --production
RUN npm run build
RUN cp dist/app.js ../../
RUN chown -hR node:0 /project \
    && chmod -R g=u /project

WORKDIR /project

ENV NODE_PATH=/project/user-app/node_modules

ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV PORT 3000

USER node

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Error I get

```
> Executing task: appsody debug --network masterdata-microservice_default --docker-options '--env KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092' -p 3002:3000 -p 9231:9229 -p 8082:8080 <

Running debug environment
Using local cache for image dev.local/appsody/jazzcash-appsody-stack:0.4
Running command: docker run --rm -p 3002:3000 -p 9231:9229 -p 8082:8080 --name payment-and-transaction-microservice --network masterdata-microservice_default -v /Volumes/Office/jazzcash/payment-and-transaction-microservice/:/project/user-app -v appsody-payment-and-transaction-microservice-20220220132730.53265500:/project/user-app/node_modules -v appsody-controller-0.3.5:/.appsody --env "KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092" -t --entrypoint /.appsody/appsody-controller dev.local/appsody/jazzcash-appsody-stack:0.4 "--mode=debug"
[Container] Running APPSODY_PREP command: npm install --prefix user-app && npm run build --prefix user-app
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /project/user-app/node_modules
[Container] npm WARN The package nyc is included as both a dev and production dependency.
[Container] 
[Container] npm ERR! code EACCES
[Container] npm ERR! syscall access
[Container] npm ERR! path /project/user-app/node_modules
[Container] npm ERR! errno -13
[Container] npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/project/user-app/node_modules'
[Container] npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/project/user-app/node_modules'] {
[Container] npm ERR!   errno: -13,
[Container] npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
[Container] npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
[Container] npm ERR!   path: '/project/user-app/node_modules'
[Container] npm ERR! }
[Container] npm ERR! 
[Container] npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
[Container] npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
[Container] npm ERR! 
[Container] npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
[Container] npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
[Container] npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
[Container] 
[Container] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[Container] npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/.npm/_logs/2022-02-20T09_10_57_749Z-debug.log
[Container] [Error] FATAL error APPSODY_PREP command received an error.  The controller is exiting: exit status 243
[Error] Error in 'appsody debug': exit status 1
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'appsody debug --network masterdata-microservice_default --docker-options '--env KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092' -p 3002:3000 -p 9231:9229 -p 8082:8080'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Answer (score -1):

Recently I changed my username and then installed docker, but docker got wrong path in configs

You need to change the dataFolder in the ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json file to the new user name and start Docker Desktop again.

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6201